# Is that possible to use Vue 3 compiled/build into Vue 2 project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create new project using Vue 3 typescript, but I want to use this project into my existing Vue 2 , why I am using this ? Because I need to fully revamp the website ,but to revamp this need time, and you know that Product Manager want those things release sooner 
So I can't do fully revamp done by rewrite , it gonna be per Phase

My ways are make the components on Vue 3 and then build it to define on Vue 3 project

Is that possible ? Or is that any way to solve this ?

Comment: You can either make them as compatible with both frameworks as they can be (probably with vue-demi), or use Vue 3 sub-apps inside Vue 2.

Comment: What does mean Vue 3 sub-apps? , Is that mean I create Vue demi project or I add Vue demi library either in vie 3 project or vue 3 project?

Comment: A nested Vue 3 app is instantiated inside Vue 2. This includes the use of Vue 3 web components, see https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/web-components.html . vue-demi means that you need stick to Vue 2 and use API that will require little changes when switching to Vue 3 later.

Comment: Is that mean I need to deploy or build Vue 3 components? And then build it and serve like CDN? Ks that what meant

Comment: You need to build V3 comps. Whether you use CDN, or private NPM package, or else to get them in V2 doesn't really matter, they are just another JS lib at this moment that needs to be imported somehow.

Comment: Really , does it mean it gonna be ok if I create external libary components? And then use it on Vue 2?

Comment: In this case, yes, because they use different project settings and `vue` package version.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't use Vue 3 components in a Vue 2 project, but you can do the inverse. Use the [Vue 3 migration build](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html) to enable Vue 2 components in a Vue 3 project. This build was designed with the purpose of progressively migrating your Vue 2 project to the new version, which sounds like what you're trying to do.

If in a Vue 3 project, when installing a Vue 2 NPM package that has a peer dependency on Vue 2 (such as `vue-select`), you'll encounter an installation error like this:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: vue3-with-vue-select@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"^3.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"2.x" from vue-select@3.12.2
npm ERR! node_modules/vue-select
npm ERR!   vue-select@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

To resolve the error, use the `--force` flag:

```
npm install --force --save vue-select
```

Comment: @Harmnot Here's a demo of Vue 3 with vue-select, using the migration build: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-with-vue-select?file=src%2FApp.vue

Comment: Regarding the warnings, you're likely referring to the Vue 2 peer dependency warnings during the NPM installation. Those warnings can be ignored, since we know that peer dependency is not relevant in a Vue 3 migration project. Use the `--force` flag to enable the installation to succeed.

Comment: Do what manually? Isn't the objective to completely migrate your project to Vue 3?