# Loading a Vue 2 component in Vue 3 with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, import, vuejs3, vue-component

I started a new project with vue cli and vite. Vue version 3.3.4. And using typescript.

Now I'm trying to import the vue-concise-slider in one of my components. https://github.com/warpcgd/vue-concise-slider

Upon using
`import {slider, slideritem} from 'vue-concise-slider'`
i get an error 'no declaration file found'. Then i created a directory types/vue-concise-slider and an index.d.ts file in there and put the line
`declare module 'vue-concise-slider';`
in it. The error in vue file went away but now in console i see a 't2._self' is undefined. Below is my ts.config

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18/tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "vite.config.*",
    "vitest.config.*",
    "cypress.config.*",
    "nightwatch.conf.*",
    "playwright.config.*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68817303/is-that-possible-to-use-vue-3-compiled-build-into-vue-2-project), following these steps should do the trick.

Your question is duplicated.